# sudo systemctl start returns "Failed to wait for response: Success"

Tags: mysql, linux, nginx, archlinux

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-lemp-nginx-mysql-php-stack-on-arch-linux) to install nginx and mysql on a new server.

I'm running into problems when I run either of `sudo systemctl start mysqld && mysql_secure_installation` or `sudo systemctl start nginx`.

With either of these I get the response "Failed to wait for response: Success". I'm not sure what this means, but I assume it means something went wrong. Do you have any idea what this message means and what I can do about it?

Comment: I can't reproduce that. `sudo systemctl start mysqld` and `sudo systemctl start nginx` executes without error. `sudo systemctl start mysql_secure_installation` doesn't find mysql_secure_installation.service

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue with `systemctl` where `start` and `stop` command would always fail, but the services were getting started and stopped correctly.

You can check if the services are effectively getting started and stopped correctly with `systemctl status service-name`.

I have also seen the mentioned error message `Failed to wait for response: Success` in many other post out there, so it seems to be a problem with `systemctl`.

After upgrading package `systemd` to version 215-4 the problem went away.

In my particular case the situation was worse, because `systemctl` failures were blocking package installation.

Namely, package `systemd` depends on package `udev`, but package `udev` could not be configured because service start/stop operations would fail.

The solution was to force the installation of package `systemd` ignoring `udev` dependency, and fix dependencies after.

```
# dpkg --ignore-depends=udev --install /var/cache/apt/archives/systemd_215-4_amd64.deb
# apt-get install -f
```